# Working with classes Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, class

I'm new to VC++ and I'm trying to work with classes.  My subroutine worked fine as straight code, but I Keep getting errors when I try using it in a class
Here is the code for the header file.

```
            [using namespace std;
#ifndef Deck_h
#define Deck_h
class Deck
{
       public:
// Default constructor
Deck();
//Destructor
~Deck();
// access functions
//function1
// Member variables

int InDeck[53];
int OutDeck[53];



  };

 #endif
```

Here is the code for the .cpp file

```
            #include "StdAfx.h"
    #include "Deck.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    &Deck::Deck()

    { // start of Deck
        int InDeck[53];
        int OutDeck[53];
        int icard;
        int isuit=1;

        for(int i = 1; i<=52; i++)
            { // Begin For i
            icard = i % 13;
            if(icard ==  0){icard=13;}
            InDeck[i] = isuit * 1000 + icard;
            OutDeck[i] = 0;
            if(icard == 13 ){isuit ++;}
        }// end of for i...
        // Randomize InDeck into OutDeck
        int t = 0;  
        srand(time_t(NULL));
        for(int j = 1; j<=52; j++)
        { // begin for j
            icard = rand() % 52 +1;
            t = 0;
            while (OutDeck[icard] >= 1000)
            { // while
                t++;
                icard = rand() % 52 +1;
                if(t > 10)
                { // Don't take too long shuffling
                    for(int k=1; k<=52; k++)
                    { // put card in first empty slot
                        if(OutDeck[k] < 1000) {
                            icard = k;
                            t  = 0;
                            break;
                        } // empty slot found
                    }  //end of for k... 
                    } // end of if t > 1000

            } //end while
            OutDeck[icard] = InDeck[j];

        } // end for j  
    } // end of Deck
```

And here is the code using the class

```
          Deck mydeck;

array<PictureBox ^, 1> ^ pix = gcnew array<PictureBox ^, 1>(10);
pix[0] = this->pb1;
pix[1] = this->pb2;
pix[2] = this->pb3;
pix[3] = this->pb4;
pix[4] = this->pb5;
pix[5] = this->pb6;
pix[6] = this->pb7;
pix[7] = this->pb8;
pix[8] = this->pb9;
pix[9] = this->pb10;


for(int p  = 1; p<= 10; p++)
{pix[p-1]->Image = Bitmap::FromFile("c:\\users\\Bob K\\Documents\\pictures\\" +             System::Convert::ToString(mydeck.OutDeck[p]) + ".bmp"); 
}

        } //End of Form1 load
```

These are the error messages

> 1>  Deck.cpp
>   1>  Generating Code...
>   1>CardsOne.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000013) "public: __clrcall Deck::~Deck(void)" (??1Deck@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall CardsOne::Form1::Form1_Load(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?Form1_Load@Form1@CardsOne@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
>   
> 1>CardsOne.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __clrcall Deck::~Deck(void)" (??1Deck@@$$FQAM@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall CardsOne::Form1::Form1_Load(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?Form1_Load@Form1@CardsOne@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
>   
> 1>C:\Users\Bob K\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CardsOne\Debug\CardsOne.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
>   
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I would appreciate any help anyone can give me

Comment: that's not C++, that's C++/CX or C++/CLI please tag appropriately.

Comment: You've got a lot of strange stuff in your code. Why does your deck have *53* cards? And what's the `&` in `&Deck::Deck()`? Within the body of the constructor you're creating 2 local variables `InDeck` and `OutDeck` that will shadow the data members having the same name. You're indexing from [1, 52] instead of [0, 52). Finally, C++/CLI *is not* C++!

Answer (score 1):

Define your destructor, in the header maybe, or even dont write `~Deck();` if you don t use it

Answer (score 1):

The linker is saying "You told me in your .h file that there would be a `~Deck` function somewhere, but I can't find its definition."

Since you're not using the destructor, just delete `~Deck();` from your header.